# Listening to events after they may have occurred

Tags: javascript, jquery

In seems in Javascript, at least in the jQuery library and the WebSocket API, you bind to events possibly after they occurred, but still are able to catch them. I have two examples and I don't understand how they are possible other than luck/timing (that is somehow always 100%, so obviously that's not it).

**jQuery**

Take jQuery's AJAX library. Somehow you can make the call and then catch the events

```
$.post(url, data)
   .done(function(response){
       console.log(response);
   });
```

I've clearly already sent the `post` off. How can I attach a 'done' event to it after the fact?

**WebSocket**

Same deal. As soon as you create a websocket, it will try to connect. How again can I catch the open event, aka connected event, after it's probably already open? Do both these apparatuses rely on the fact that these connections will undoubetbly take *some* time? Probably slower than it is to process the actual code?

```
let ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:123');
ws.addEventListener('open', function(event){
   console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: That's not an event handler; it's a Promise callback.

Comment: Still - what if the request is already done? If it happened instantly, and now it wants to go through all callbacks, it may be too late?

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, all the current code happens before the request has time to finish. In the instances of Promises that are immediately resolved/rejected, the callbacks get immediately called as soon as they are set

Answer (score 1):

These are called callbacks.

Callbacks are handled when an event returns a "finished" status. This is a part of the language. It's "under the hood" which is why it isn't visible to you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

This is an introduction to callbacks from MDN.

Regarding event handlers:

Javascript is an adaptively compiled language in present day, and how exactly that works depends on the engine.

http://voidcanvas.com/is-javascript-really-interpreted-or-compiled-language/

Here's a reference that sort of scratches the surface.

Comment: They are not callbacks, they are event handlers. They are bound (possibly) after the function is called. Think about the logic. You tell `Jimmy.to.drive()` and THEN you tell the `car.on.drive( () => logStart )`. Well guess what, the car is already driving.. so the log shouldn't get called.

Comment: The function that is called by the event handler is the callback.

I guess maybe I didn't understand your question. Are you asking how event handlers work in javascript in general?

Comment: Yes - how can we possibly be attaching events (as in the WebSocket example) to processes that may have already occurred? `WebSocket.connect` THEN `WebSocket.onConnect => doMyThing()`..

Comment: Ahhh... You DO realize that javascript code is actually compiled before runtime as well as being read at runtime, right? Thus, the event handler is attached to the event at page opening (as I understand it.) Modern javascript engines are adaptive compilers.

Comment: Oh, is this true? I thought it was simply run line by line. Read a line, execute it, move on. Is there more info on this?

Comment: @jozenbasin I added a link to my initial answer that provides a little explanation. They're using JIT (Just In Time) compilation, immediately before execution, usually. The problem is that the ECMA script isn't specific on the compiler requirements, so different JS engines handle the problem in different ways. V8 uses a mixture of C++ and javascript in their engine, and the specifics of each engine are complex enough to have a book written about them.

Answer (score 0):

> Do both these apparatuses rely on the fact that these connections will undoubetbly take some time?

That is spot on. For longer running processes, we sometimes don't want to block the execution of all other code. That is the power of asynchronous calls.

We can allow for a program to continue execution while waiting for a longer running process to complete.

So in your jQuery AJAX example, a HTTP POST request is sending `data` to a server at `url`

Since a call to a server can take some time, we may want to run other code as the program waits for a response from the server.

So if this block of code were to execute

```
$.post(url, data)
   .done(function(response){
       console.log("I finally got a response from the server!");
});

console.log("I'm not gonna wait for that response.");
```

You would see the second log statement printed first, i.e. `"I'm not gonna wait for that response."`, because the HTTP request would still be processing.

Once a response returns, the first log statement will be printed, as the request is now complete.

The `$.post(url, data)` function call by itself returns a Deferred object, which is an interface to handle events tied to asynchronous processes.

In this case, the `done` event is available for the program to process whatever response has returned from the server.

You can find other event handlers made available by the Deferred object here: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

All this can apply to the WebSocket example as well. The function you pass as the second parameter is just a handler to process the result of the connection attempt, whether it happened successfully or not.